# React Native Webview push new page on <a> clicked

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm trying to create a hybrid react native app to host my website's content in webviews. Something like this: [Supreme App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/supreme/id664573705?mt=8)

One thing I want to achieve is: when a `<a href>` link is clicked on my website, instead of webview just show the new link's content, I want the app to push a new page and show the new link content in the new page, so that I can maintain a good page backstack and it feels more like native app (for each navigation, there's a new page for it).

I'm wondering how I can detect link click, push a new page instead of let the webview do default link navigation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebView` prop `onNavigationStateChange` to detect the change in url.

On clicking `<a>` the `webview` will redirect, the `onNavigationStateChange` will fire. You can use this callback to push a new screen in the app.

Eg.

```
       <WebView
             ref={r => this.webview = r}
             style = {{marginTop : 0}}
             onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange}
             source = {{uri: 'https://www.your-url.com' }}
       />


      _onNavigationStateChange=(webViewState)=>{
          let newUrl = webViewState.url
          /*Your navigation logic*/
       }
```

[Reference](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onnavigationstatechange)